# When I copy multiple divs in html page in Chrome it adds weird characters

Tags: html, google-chrome, line

I created simple page

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div>111</div>
  <div>22</div>
</body>
</html>
```

when I copy with ctrl+c the texts 111 and 22 and paste it into the Chrome search (ctrl+f) its add weird char and because of this it does not find anything:

[image]

What can I do to copy my text and find also the "new line" by divs?

Comment: It is a representation of a CRLF

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue in Chrome when I format your code

Comment: @mplungjan i dont know why? maybe i using rtl chrome?